# Why does CSRF fail even though there is a CSRF token in Django?

Tags: django, csrf

I am building a login form with Django and it shows a CSRF error. The template is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TaxNow</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header>

</header>
<script>
$("document").ready(function () {
$("header").load("static/header.html");
})
</script>
<div id="loginbox">
<h3>Log In to Access TaxNow</h3>
<div id="invalidCredentials"></div>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000" method="POST">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br><br>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"><br>
<button id="login" type="submit">Log In</button></br>
    {% csrf_token %}</form>
<a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a><br>
<a href="forgotCredentials.html">Forgot Username/Password?</a>
<script> params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
params.get('name');
var GET = params.getAll('invalidCredentials')
if (GET[0] == "true") {
$("#invalidCredentials").innerHTML = "Invalid username or password."
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `views.py` function is like so:

```
def logIn(request):
    if not User.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "taxnow/app/login.html")
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #other paths
    path('startFile', views.logIn, name="logIn")

]
```

Something intresting is that there is a cookie here:
[image]

I have used the `@csrf_exempt` decorator but IDK whether this is safe. Any thoughts?

Comment: i checked your code there was no such error

Comment: make the csrf tag first line in the form tag

Comment: @1aryo1 it is still not working